# How to access systemImage of MKMapItem from MKLocalSerch results

Tags: swiftui, mapkit, mklocalsearch

MKLocalSearch returns an array of MKMapItems, which are created with an appropriate systemImage for the balloon.  I'm trying to merge those results with my custom existing Markers so both are selectable.

Is there any way to determine the systemImage from the MKMapItem that MKLocalSearch returns? I've looked at GEOFeatureStyleAttributes but it does not seem to be there.

I think I could work around this by just picking a systemImage based on the search text, but the MKLocalSearch returns several distinct systemImages for a simple search.  For example, "Restaurants" returns images for seafood, food trucks, pizza, as well as a more generic knife&fork.

Comment: I don't think apple provides it but you could map some with the category it shouldn't take much you can do an extension.

Comment: Thanks, it appears that's the case - the selected image from searchResults is not discoverable.